# **make: *** [out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/core_intermediates/classes.dex] Error 1****

Tags: android, ubuntu-10.10, devkit

Im new to Linux.Im porting android on devkit8000(copy of beagleboard) but getting so many errors in compiling the android source code.Below is the result of "make" command.

```
============================================ 
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL     
PLATFORM_VERSION=2.2 
TARGET_PRODUCT=devkit8000 
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng 
TARGET_SIMULATOR= 
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release 
TARGET_BUILD_APPS= 
TARGET_ARCH=arm 
HOST_ARCH=x86 
HOST_OS=linux 
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release 
BUILD_ID=MASTER 
============================================ 
Install: out/host/linux-x86/framework/apicheck.jar 
Install: out/host/linux-x86/framework/clearsilver.jar 
Install: out/host/linux-x86/framework/droiddoc.jar 
Install: out/host/linux-x86/lib/libneo_util.so 
Install: out/host/linux-x86/lib/libneo_cs.so 
Install: out/host/linux-x86/lib/libneo_cgi.so 
Install: out/host/linux-x86/lib/libclearsilver-jni.so 
Copying: out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/core_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar 
Install: out/host/linux-x86/framework/dx.jar 
Install: out/host/linux-x86/bin/dx 
**target Dex: core 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/dx/command/Main 
**make: *** [out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/core_intermediates/classes.dex] Error 1****
```

i couldnt find correct solution for this error.plz help:(

Comment: Have you found a solution for this issue?